# List of Kavanot for ANA BE-KHOACH

Tags: tefilla, sefirat-ha-omer, kavana-concentration, kabbalat-shabbat, korbanos-ketores-prayers

What are some of the things one should have in mind (kavanah) when saying Ana B'Khoach?

Comment: Why would you think you should have anything special in mind there as opposed to somewhere else?

Comment: @Scimonster, you remind me of my mother. If she buys me a green sweater and a red sweater and I wear the green, she'll ask me: "What, you don't like the red?" This guy's asking a question about Ana beKoah. He can't ask about everything in the one question.

Comment: @ShimonbM The point is, he posted this question with an answer, and the question is unmotivated. It looks like just a place to post the answer.

Comment: @Scimonster - Oh, I see now. Hey, you responded really quickly! Are you *sure* you're not my mother?

Answer (score 6):

> While saying this paragraph [Ana Bechoach], one should look at - or envisage - the Sheimos (Divine Names) formed by the acronyms of its words, but one should not pronounce them.

http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/28.htm#t206

Comment: +1. The _Minhagim_ seems to be referring to its recitation in _kabalas Shabas_ specifically. The SIE site cites this to _Hayom Yom_. Is there any indication in the latter of whether it's speaking of its recitation generally or in _kabalas Shabas_ specifically?

Answer (score 5):

The meaning (translation, if you think in a language other than Hebrew) of the words.

Answer (score 3):

- The 42 words represent the 42 letters of the Ve'Ahavta (paragraph from Shema Deuteronomy 6:5-9).
- The 42 words can be divided up into seven lines of six words each, and each letter from the six words can be combined into the end of each of the six to make a seventh "word" for each line making the title 49, and these 49 represent each day of Sefirat ha-Omer, as well as the 49 words that are in Psalm 67.

Answer (score 2):

During Sefiras HaOmer Ana Bekoach is used to connect to each day.

There are 7 words on each line of Ana Bekoach including the acronym that is one of the names of Hashem. Each one matches up with one of the 7 lower sefiros Chesed, Gevurah, Tiferes, Netzach, Hod, Yesod, Malchus.

During Sefiras HaOmer at least amongst Chassidim and Sephardim, a person connects each Sefirah to one of the words

Example Ana is Chesed S'B'Chesed and so on.

Comment: It's tagged "Kabbalas Shabbos"

Comment: @ShmuelBrin If you understand Kabbalah then you realize it isnt mutually exlusive. I was simply clarifying my source so users wouldnt wonder where I got the idea that each word of Ana BeKoach connects to a Sefirah S'B'Serfirah which you could meditate on any time you say it except that could take all day.

Answer (score 2):

[image: The acronym of each line should be concentrated upon]

The Arizal says that these letters correspond to the Shem Mem Bet (see Sidur Kawanat HaLev for the Peshat of the words). Of course, one should always concentrate on the Peshat of the words and then the Sod (Ben Ish Hai in Sefer Tikun Tefila).