# Ana B'koach in prayers

Tags: tefilla

There are certain places within prayer, where we mention this interesting prayer. Just wanted to know why do we say Ana B'koach in those certain places?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17015/15256

Comment: It only has 1, but there are others where no one has spoken about them.

Comment: This is why it is only related and not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This 42 letter arrangement, also called the 42 letter name of G-d, is actually related to the mystical intention aspect of prayers and is something that we are to meditate on at different points.

It is associated with the process of converting things from one state to another, in Hebrew called *it’hapcha*.

This type of activity is associated with the feminine which is also why the small sum gematria of the names of the 4 Matriarchs is also 42. (שרה, רבקה, לאה, רחל)

One example in prayer of when we are to meditate on this 42 letter name is while reciting the 2nd section of the Shema (the paragraph which begins *v’ahavta*), which contains 42 words. While pronouncing each word, one intends the corresponding letter from the 42 letter name.

Comment: Ithapcha sounds Aramaic not Hebrew

Comment: @robev The root is הפך. It’s Biblical Hebrew.

Comment: Didn't say otherwise

Comment: @Yaacov Deane that is explaining what ana bkoach is.  I want to know why we say it at certain points.

Comment: @Russell For the reason I point out in the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: @Yaacov Deane Not sure how that expresses the answer.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Please explain what the recitation is achieving in each of the cases where it appears.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok That’s a separate, good and different question. If you ask it specifying which particular places in the siddur you are interested in, it will probably get attention. If you are looking for more detailed information, you might find Sefer Pardes Rimonim by Rabbi Moshe Cordovero of interest.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I thought that was the question of the OP who says, "Just wanted to know why do we say Ana B'koach in those *certain* places?"

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok The OP enumerated nothing specific so I understood the question to be about what is generally going on in all those places within the siddur where the Ana b’Koach appears.  Your question is much bigger since it would have to address how the Ana b’Koach relates to the particular emphasis in each spot. They are not identical because the surrounding environment changes.